# Overriding field values in Drupal 8

Tags: theming, hooks

I am attempting to override a node field value in Drupal 8 (on output) using template_preprocess_node. Specifically, I am attempting to override the text of a long text field. I am currently using this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['field_content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<p>Testing 123</p>',
  );
}
```

And that works, but it totally overrides the field, removing the classes I added to the field wrapper, etc.

Does anyone know how to just set the value only, without replacing the entire field theming, etc? I do *not* want to manually add the field wrapper classes to #markup.

Comment: get rid off markup and try `'#type' => 'processed_text',  '#text' => 'Testing 123',`

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Unfortunately that does the same thing (removing field wrappers). Is there a list of these options somewhere? I've been looking for that.

Comment: You flushed the cache, right?

Comment: Yup--that's how I got the change to show up.

Comment: How did you add the class to the field wrapper?

Comment: I did it in template_preprocess_field.

Comment: What if you move that proprocess_field code after preprocess_node?

Comment: It actually already does come after in the .theme file. I may just end up doing this differently and adding the wrapper along with the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a quick test, turns out that **hook_preprocess_node** will always override **hook_preprocess_field**'s attributes.

Therefore, instead of adding the class in **hook_preprocess_field**, and if you don't want to use `'#markup'`, you could add it in **hook_preprocess_node** like this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $variables['content']['field_test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'processed_text', 
    '#text' => 'Test 123',
    '#prefix' => '<div class="your-class">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
}
```

Comment: Yup, thanks for looking into that--adding prefix/suffix works fine. I ended up switching back to using markup because I didn't want the extra <p> tags from processed_text. Thanks again!